# リダイレクト設定すると絶対パスが表示されてしまいます。

Tags: .htaccess

URL間違いに伴い、下記のように301リダイレクトを設置しました。
しかし、リダイレクト先が絶対パスになってしまいうまくアクセスできません。

## コードの記述

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^gallery/design/bellipaint-design-([0-9]{3})/$ 
gallery/design/bellypaint-design-$1/ [R=301,L]
```

## リダイレクトされた結果

https://www.heartkoru.com/home/heartkoru/heartkoru.com/public_html/gallery/design/bellypaint-design-001/

本来は下記のようにならなければなりません。
https://www.heartkoru.com/gallery/design/bellypaint-design-001/

解決方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授いただけますと大変助かります。

なお、全記述は下記の通りです。

---

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

#www有りに正規化
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(heartkoru\.com)(:80)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.heartkoru.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#index.htmlなしに正規化
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ https://www.heartkoru.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#SSLリダイレクト
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#404ページへの誘導
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lightbox=
RewriteRule ^/gallery/? [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^gallery/design/bellipaint-design-([0-9]{3})/$ gallery/design/bellypaint-design-$1/ [R=301,L]

#ページ単位の301
Redirect permanent /princess https://www.heartkoru.com/bellypaint-menu/princess/
Redirect permanent /babyphoto-1 https://www.heartkoru.com/mother/baby-photo/
Redirect permanent /maternitypaint-design?lightbox=image_1ssd https://www.heartkoru.com/gallery/
Redirect permanent /maternity-photo https://www.heartkoru.com/bellypaint-menu/maternity-photo/
Redirect permanent /bellypaint https://www.heartkoru.com/bellypaint-menu/
Redirect permanent /maternitypaint-design https://www.heartkoru.com/gallery/
Redirect permanent /aboutus https://www.heartkoru.com/about/
Redirect permanent /babyphoto https://www.heartkoru.com/mother/breastfeeding/
Redirect permanent /bellypaint-memo https://www.heartkoru.com/about/
Redirect permanent /blank https://www.heartkoru.com/copyright/
Redirect permanent /blank-1 https://www.heartkoru.com/gift/
Redirect permanent /maori https://www.heartkoru.com/bellypaint-menu/maori/
Redirect permanent /staff https://www.heartkoru.com/about/
Redirect permanent /menu3 https://www.heartkoru.com/faq/
Redirect permanent /menu1 https://www.heartkoru.com/about/
Redirect permanent /company https://www.heartkoru.com/about/
Redirect permanent /staff-1 https://www.heartkoru.com/about/
Redirect permanent /maternitypaint-design https://www.heartkoru.com/gallery/
Redirect permanent /petit-flower https://www.heartkoru.com/bellypaint-menu/petit-flower/
Redirect permanent /originalgoods https://www.heartkoru.com/gift/
Redirect permanent /trial https://www.heartkoru.com/bellypaint-menu/trial/
Redirect permanent /decoart https://www.heartkoru.com/bellypaint-menu/
Redirect permanent /#!bellypaint-menu/ https://www.heartkoru.com/bellypaint-menu/
Redirect permanent /gallery/?lightbox=dataItem-j2qspwgr https://www.heartkoru.com/gallery/
Redirect permanent /gallery/?lightbox=dataItem-it14z4i8 https://www.heartkoru.com/gallery/

#gzip圧縮
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$ no-gzip dont-vary
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI _\.utxt$ no-gzip
#DeflateCompressionLevel 4
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom_xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
</IfModule>
SetEnvIf Request_URI ".*" AllowCountry
```

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteBase /` を追加してみてください。

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

#www有りに正規化
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /  <- 追加
 ：：：
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！！できました！！大変、助かりました！